# Why when a component is wrapped inside a High Order Component, the new component does not have any of the static methods of the original component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I read about it in the [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over) but I don't understand why it happens.

Furthermore, I'd really appreciate if you could describe a practical example in which one could attach to a component a static method that gets lost once it's wrapped in a HOC. The React doc talks about the Relay containers, but I never used it, I would need a simpler example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more robust example. The reason static values aren't available when using a higher order component (for example, `enhance` in the example below) is because the component being composed or wrapped it wrapped by *another* component. So the resulting component doesn't have the static methods of the component passed in (unless explicitly copied like `enhanceAndHoist` in the example below).

However, it's often desirable for this to happen for all static methods which can be done with the [`hoist-non-react-statics`](https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics) package as stated in the docs and is actually used by many other packages that provide higher order components.

For example, the last line in `react-redux`'s `connect` method is to hoist statics: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/b6b47995acfb8c1ff5d04a31c14aa75f112a47ab/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L432

```
// Line from react-redux
return hoistStatics(Connect, WrappedComponent)
```

```js
const enhance = Wrapped => {
  return class Enhanced extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Wrapped injectedProp="foo" />;
    }
  };
};

const WrappedComponent = props => <div>{props.injectedProp}</div>;

// Define a static method
WrappedComponent.staticValue = "baz";

// Now apply a HOC
const EnhancedComponent = enhance(WrappedComponent);

console.log(`WrappedComponent.staticValue: ${WrappedComponent.staticValue}`); // "baz"
console.log(`EnhancedComponent.staticValue: ${EnhancedComponent.staticValue}`); // undefined

const enhanceAndHoist = Wrapped => {
  const result = class Enhanced extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Wrapped injectedProp="foo" />;
    }
  };

  // Manually "hoist" the static value.
  result.staticValue = Wrapped.staticValue;

  return result;
};

// Now apply a HOC
const EnhancedAndHoistedComponent = enhanceAndHoist(WrappedComponent);

console.log(`WrappedComponent.staticValue: ${WrappedComponent.staticValue}`); // "baz"
console.log(
  `EnhancedAndHoistedComponent.staticValue: ${
    EnhancedAndHoistedComponent.staticValue
  }`
); // "baz"

function App() {
  return <EnhancedComponent />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, but despite it to me it's still not clear `why the resulting component doesn't have the static methods of the component passed`.

Comment: Without explicitly assigned the static value (as in the example of `enhanceAndHoist`) how would the static property from `Wrapped` get added to the `Enhanced` component class?

Comment: I don't know, but I expected the static property from `Wrapped` to get added "automatically" in the `Enhanced` component class...why it doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please do Mind me. I'm learning as well. But I believe, my answer is meaningful. Though not explicit.

The Reason Static Entities of a Class are not taken into account, In General, is because React doesn't takes into the account what Classes are but what Class consists of (the final product from the class).

The method `React.createElement()` takes prop values and the components' Instance by calling the Class. Consider an example Component :

```
<Text className="danger">Hello React</Text>
```

The Component Roughly after a Babel Transpilation :

```
  React.createElement(
    Text, // Component
    { className: 'danger' }, // Component className
    'Hello React' // Component children
  )
```

The First Parameter of the method has to be an `HTMLElement`, to which the other props and children would be passed into. Which would mean that Class is Instantiated, and an Object is returned.

I am considering @skovy's Example. After defining a static method, and passing it to a Higer Order Component, it returns the Object with properties needed to build the HTML :

```
const WrappedComponent = props => <div>{props.injectedProp}</div>;

// Define a static method
WrappedComponent.staticValue = "baz";

console.log((Object.getOwnPropertyNames(<WrappedComponent />)))
// Logs : ['$$typeof', 'type', 'key', 'ref', 'props', '_owner', '_store', '_self', '_source']

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(React.createElement(WrappedComponent)))
// Logs : {$$typeof: {…}, type: {…}, key: {…}, ref: {…}, props: {…}, …}
```

They are not from a Class, but a Class that returns an Instantiated Object that is further processed.

Since, the Component that is returned from Higher Order Component, which itself is an Object, and not a class.

```
const EnhancedComponent = enhance(WrappedComponent);
```

The `EnhancedComponent` itself doesn't have any class associated with it to add the Static Entities to itself only the Objects of `WrappedComponent`. Because that is what is returned from `<WrappedComponent />` + Obviously Objects don't inherit static Entities from its Classes.

A further analysis would need to look at the `Index.d.ts` file that points to the Reference for `React.createElement()`. But it seems React doesn't takes into account what is defined in Class. But only what it returns. And validates the same.

There's a discussion - yet [this one](https://github.com/acdlite/flummox/issues/173#issuecomment-98865891) would be helpful in understanding - that Static Properties / Methods are used less in React overall.

Additionally, the [new React Documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/) indicates a direction towards Functions & Functional Programming, rather than using Classes.

However, if needed to be used. It's best to extract them individually, and again explicitly writing them to the new Components created from HOC.